# Text Visible in other Activities,

Tags: android, text, textview, fragment

i just needed some quick help. I got a nav drawer setup, and i use activity main as my welcome screen, so I put a text box on the activity_main, but the problem is that when I chose other nav drawer pages, i see the text box from the activity main.

What one of my activity pages should look like: http://puu.sh/nQFkc/1ed83811cc.png

What it ends up looking like: http://puu.sh/nQF93/785c9eee45.png

Need to mention im new to android?

Main Activity

```
package nota.outlawsindex;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String[] mNavigationDrawerItemTitles;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
Toolbar toolbar;
Scrollview scrollView;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mNavigationDrawerItemTitles =         getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navigation_drawer_items_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);


    setupToolbar();

    DataModel[] drawerItem = new DataModel[4];//need to update this if you     add start counting at 0

    drawerItem[0] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_connect, "Calculate     Sentence");
    drawerItem[1] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_fixtures, "Felonies");
    drawerItem[2] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_table, "Misdemeanors");
    drawerItem[3] = new DataModel(R.drawable.ic_drawer, "Infractions");
    //add on to the list to create more pages
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view_item_row, drawerItem);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    setupDrawerToggle();



}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

}

private void selectItem(int position) {



    scrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new ConnectFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new FixturesFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new TableFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new SelfAddedFragment();
            break;
        //add more cases if you add more pages

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,             fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

void setupToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}

void setupDrawerToggle() {
    mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
    //This is necessary to change the icon of the Drawer Toggle upon state change.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

}

Activity_Main

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </RelativeLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        </FrameLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="26dp" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:focusable="false">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?         android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:text="              Welcome to The Outlaw&apos;s                                                 Index! An app designed for individuals who want to educate themselves with knowledge regarding different types of offenses in the United States. Currently this app is directed towards individuals in the United States, but a Canadian version may be released in upcoming months. This app gives users the tools and resources to research different classes of offenses and the repercussions one would receive if convicted. Although this app is informative, advice from law enforcement, attorneys, and other members of the law should be considered more accurate as it may suit your personal needs regarding a specific case. To start off, choose any of the classes on the left hand side, or calculate a sentence and the repercussions that would follow."
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:password="false"
                    android:phoneNumber="false"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_above="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="27dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/menuBackgroundColor"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/colorAccent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"/>
<!--    because there is no header in this one I am using android:paddingTop="15dp"
    to push the menu below the level of the translucent top bar.-->
```

One of my Navdrawer pages (Same one as in screenshots)

Fragment

```
package nota.outlawsindex;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class TableFragment extends Fragment {

Button MisdemeanorClassAButton = null;
Button MisdemeanorClassBButton = null;
Button MisdemeanorClassCButton = null;
Button MisdemeanorClassDButton = null;
TextView MisdemeanorText;


public TableFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_table, container, false);
    init(rootView);
    return rootView;

}


public void init(View view) {
    MisdemeanorClassAButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.MisdemeanorClassAButton);
    MisdemeanorText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MisdemeanorText);
    MisdemeanorClassAButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                                    MisdemeanorText.setText(R.string.MA);
                                                }
                                            }
    );
    MisdemeanorClassBButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.MisdemeanorClassBButton);
    MisdemeanorText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MisdemeanorText);
    MisdemeanorClassBButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                   public void onClick(View view) {
                                                       MisdemeanorText.setText(R.string.MB);
                                                   }
                                               }
    );
    MisdemeanorClassCButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.MisdemeanorClassCButton);
    MisdemeanorText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MisdemeanorText);
    MisdemeanorClassCButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                   public void onClick(View view) {
                                                       MisdemeanorText.setText(R.string.MC);
                                                   }
                                               }
    );
    MisdemeanorClassDButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.MisdemeanorClassDButton);
    MisdemeanorText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MisdemeanorText);
    MisdemeanorClassDButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                   public void onClick(View view) {
                                                       MisdemeanorText.setText(R.string.MD);
                                                   }
                                               }
    );
}
}
```

The Activity Page of one of the NavDrawer Pages

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/MTB"
    android:id="@+id/MisdemeanorText"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Class A"
    android:id="@+id/MisdemeanorClassAButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Class B"
    android:id="@+id/MisdemeanorClassBButton"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/MisdemeanorClassAButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/MisdemeanorClassAButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/MisdemeanorClassAButton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Class C"
    android:id="@+id/MisdemeanorClassCButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/MisdemeanorClassBButton"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/MisdemeanorClassDButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/MisdemeanorClassDButton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Class D"
    android:id="@+id/MisdemeanorClassDButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/MisdemeanorClassCButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please paste relevant code.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari Please check at the Updated Version

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa Please check the Updated Version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your layout.
Two approaches to fix your problem -

1. Whenever you instantiate any fragment by selecting any option from the navigation drawer, you can set `ScrollView` (containing the welcome text) visibility to `GONE`.

   Scrollview scrollView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   ...

   scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

   }

   private void selectItem(int position) {

scrollView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

....

}

2. Create a one more fragment with the layout where you only show your welcome text and launch this fragment in `onCreate()` of your activity. So this will show the welcome text when user starts your app. and when user selects any item from Navdrawer, you can launch another fragment of your choice. But for this you should remove welcome text from activity layout xml.

Comment: What would be the line of code I would use for option 1 and where would i place it? MainActivity im guessing? Sorry I am new to android development

Comment: First instantiate your ScrollView and then setVisibility(View.GONE) in selectItem().

Comment: How do i instantiate ScrollView what should it equal? It tried to do it, but i think my syntax is wrong,

Comment: Like you do mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

Comment: I wrote ScrollView view = new ScrollView(); but i think that is wrong

Comment: ScrollView  scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id. scrollView);

Comment: Sorry to bother you Mr. Ansari but i cannot figure this out
I know that i need to put 
        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
and setVisibility(View.GONE) somewhere but i dont know which lines to, It is in the main activity correct? Which line to i paste these in??

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: It is telling me that Scrollview cannot be resolved, in the statement     Scrollview scrollView;
 
also it is telling me "Cannot Resolve Method setVisibility(int)

i also needed to change 

scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

 into 

ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

because of compatibility, This is API15 also, I edited this into the original question also